# Truncating decimal number to one decimal digit

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out what the best way is to parse a decimal value. I am currently using `Math.Round`, but that does not seem to work for the input data.

I want to be able to get the integer part and then the first digit after the decimal.

```
var value = 25.987817685360218441503885773M;
return Math.Round(value, 1);
```

returns `26` but I would like to return `25.9`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to round `25.987817685360218441503885773M` to `26.9`? That's not how rounding works.

Comment: Do you mean 25.9?  Also, what would you expect 25.887 to round to?  Basically, do you just want to truncate what is after the first decimal or do you need special cases when rounding to the next whole number?

Comment: Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What you are describing is not rounding.  Please explain why you want the result in your example to be 26.9.  Otherwise, we will just have to assume you misunderstand your own requirements, and you will be unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: sorry someone modified my question and removed a lot of information

Comment: @Robert : `Math.Round` works, you need the right overload, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that you want to "round" it to 25.9 not to 26.9, you have to do it manually.

```
 var number = 25.9877;
 var rounded = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToInt32(number*10))/10;
```

And, of course, this is not rounding, this is just chopping off the decimals.

Comment: @Robert - If this is the accepted answer, and you really did mean `25.9`, not `26.9`, then please edit your post to reflect this.

Comment: people keep change my results i did mean 25.9

Comment: This rounds to `26`? `Convert.ToInt32` rounds.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Math.Round has an overload for that:

```
System.Math.Round (n, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

See [Math.Round Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are rounding which will obviously round at the end. What you want to do is truncate the number. Here is a method that will accomplish what you want:

```
public decimal TruncateDecimal(decimal value, int precision)
{
    decimal step = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
    int tmp = (int)Math.Truncate(step * value);
    return tmp / step;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rounding to the first decimal, but 25.98 rounds UP. Which means 8 is >=5 and makes 9 become 0 and carry the one to 5. ie 5+1. Thus you are getting 26.

Answer (score 0):

Since there at least to my knowledge is no working solution here which does what the OP wants.

```
// .NET has no build in power function for decimals
decimal Pow(decimal value, int exp)
{
 if (exp < 0)
  return 1/Pow(value, -exp);

 if (exp == 0)
  return 1;
 else if (exp % 2 == 0)
  return Pow(value * value, exp / 2);
 else return 
  value * Pow(value, exp - 1);
}
// Rounds a number to decimals decimals, ie 1 => 1 decimal, -2 => whole hundreds
public decimal Truncate(decimal number, int decimals)
{
 var factor = 1 / Pow(10, decimals);
 return number - (number % factor);
}
```

Do keep in mind though that this is not rounding, this is some weird form of truncating.